# Spring AOP proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

My code:-

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="arthmeticCalculator" class="com.manoj.aop.test.CalculatorImpl" lazy-init="true"/>
    <bean id="stubCalculator" class="com.manoj.aop.test.StubCalculator" lazy-init="true"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
      <property name="beanNames">
        <list>
          <value>*Calculator</value>
        </list>
      </property>
      <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
          <value>methodNameAdvisor</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="methodNameAdvisor"
      class="org.springframework.aop.support.NameMatchMethodPointcutAdvisor">
     <property name="mappedNames">
      <list>
       <value>add</value>
       <value>sub</value>
      </list>
     </property>
     <property name="advice" ref="loggingAroundAdvice" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="loggingAroundAdvice" class="com.manoj.aop.test.LoggingAroundAdvice">
      <constructor-arg><ref bean="arthmeticCalculator"/></constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg><ref bean="stubCalculator"/></constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg><value>false</value></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="testService" class="com.manoj.aop.test.TestService">
    <!--  
      <property name="arthmeticCalculator" ref="arthmeticCalculator"/>
     -->
    </bean>
```

Java Code:

```
package com.manoj.aop.test;

import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class LoggingAroundAdvice implements MethodInterceptor{


       Calculator actualCalculator;
       Calculator stubCalculator;
       boolean useStub;



 public LoggingAroundAdvice(Calculator actualCalculator, Calculator stubCalculator, boolean useStub) {
   this.actualCalculator = actualCalculator;
   this.stubCalculator = stubCalculator;
   this.useStub = useStub;
  }



 public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
  System.out.println("Around Invoice called");
  Calculator calc = useStub ? stubCalculator: actualCalculator;
  System.out.println(calc.getClass().getName());
  Object result = methodInvocation.getMethod().invoke(calc, methodInvocation.getArguments());
  return result;
 }

}

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class TestService {

 @Autowired
     private Calculator  arthmeticCalculator;


     public void test(){
      System.out.println(arthmeticCalculator.getClass().getName());
      System.out.println(arthmeticCalculator.add(5, 10.5));
     }



}
```

Sorry guys I dont know how to format text in this editor,
My problem is :-

Spring is creating proxy for the class but never execute the Invoke method of the Around advice. Can some body please tell me whats going on and how to make it call the invoke method?

Here is the output of test class:-

$Proxy4
15.5

Thanks ,
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Spring are you using? The way you are doing proxy is the older way. The better way is to use the annotation or pure POJO+XML way. You can check a short introduction on AOP section [here](http://www.lalitbhatt.com/Spring)

Comment: I am using Spring3,, I want to have control on the actual instance that will be called in the invoke method of the Around invice ,thats why I am using this old style. In LoggingAroundAdvice I am checking which implementation is to use depending upon the useStub flag.But I dont know why Spring is not calling invoke() method?

Comment: Cannot you get this from ProceedingJoinPoint using the getTarget method.

Comment: Also if you can tell what you are trying  to do that will help to answer it better. I am not sure about why you want to make an advice by passing both stub and actual calculator in the advice constructor. Also your test service sits in the same configuration XML, which sounds like anti pattern to me. If you have done it for showing purpose only, than it is fine.

Comment: well, in my application some of the the services are not yet implemented. these services call back end systems to get data and eventually return me a VO. Now these systems are third party systems that aren't ready yet to give us actual data. so I am trying to stub those services using AOP. So that when I call the service from my code i will get some stubbed data and that decision is made by the 'isStub' flag which can be placed in propperties file. But the problem is invoke method never get called. some thing seriously wrong with the code I have written and I am unable to find out.